# Object methods in JavaScript with bracket notation

Tags: javascript

```js
var employee = {
  ["Last Name"]: "Smith",
  ["First Name"]: "Josh",
  ["Full Name"]: function() {
    return this["First Name"] + this["Last Name"]
  }
};
document.write("Good day" + this["Full Name"])
```

I'm currently learning JavaScript and I wanted to create an object with properties in two words using the bracket notation, unfortunately it gives me a result of `Good dayundefined` instead of `Good day Josh Smith`. I don't know what supposed to be the problem of my code...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: You'll need to invoke the function to get the result you want. You're just writing the function itself, not it's return value. So change to `document.write("Good day" + employee["Full Name"]())`, note the extra set of parens at the end.

Comment: You're using `this` outside an object method.

Comment: It should be `employee["Full Name"]()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert "Full Name" to a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), and refer to `employee` instead of this when you call it:

```js
var employee = {
  "Last Name": "Smith",
  "First Name": "Josh",
  get "Full Name"() { // convert to getter
    return `${this["First Name"]} ${this["Last Name"]}`;
  }
};

document.write("Good day " + employee["Full Name"]) // refer to  employee instead of this
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind wrapping `this["Last Name"]` and `this["First Name"]` inside the double bracket , knowing that it work fine without them ?

Comment: You need to use the bracket notation to get the value. If you're talking about the curly brackets - this is an expression inside a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 5):

Two problems.

1. You need to use `employee["First Name"]`, not `this["First Name"]`, since you're not inside an object method.
2. You need to call the function with `()`.

```js
var employee = {
  ["Last Name"]: "Smith",
  ["First Name"]: "Josh",
  ["Full Name"]: function() {
    return this["First Name"] + this["Last Name"]
  }
};
document.write("Good day" + employee["Full Name"]())
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm currently learning JavaScript and your remarks with those problems are very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var employee = { 
  "Last Name":"Smith", 
  "First Name":"Josh",
  "Full Name": function() {
    return  this["First Name"] +" "+ this["Last Name"];
  }
};
document.write("Good day " + employee["Full Name"]());
```